On duplicate key check if the other column is the same
I have a table with the following schema:
CREATE TABLE T (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    key BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    val BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
);

I need to ensure that if the key is the same, the value must also be the same, i.e. you cannot have both "foo: bar" and "foo: bar2" in the table.
Note: foo and bar stand for numeric values in this question.
But 2x "foo: bar", is allowed ("foo: bar", and another "foo: bar")
One way to do this is make key a unique constraint.
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT uk_key UNIQUE (key);

So there can only be 1 "foo: bar" in the table.
How can I safely allow insertion operations of 2 "foo: bar" in this case? i.e. both should 'succeed' even though the table has only 1 row.
I can try
SELECT * from T where key=foo FOR UPDATE;
--- if key is there, make sure it's equal to value, if so, success
--- else insert
INSERT INTO T VALUES (foo, bar);

But this isn't entirely safe. The select wouldn't lock anything if there's no row. So the insert may fail with a duplicate key constraint anyway if there are interleaved transactions going on that both do select first, hold no locks and then insert.
This leads to the next solution where I rely on the duplicate constraint:
INSERT INTO T VALUES (foo, bar);
-- if no duplicates, success
-- if duplicates, select and check
SELECT val from T where key=foo;
-- check that val == bar

Is this safe? Would MySQL (InnoDB) hold the lock on the row after insert even if it failed due to duplicate error (It's possible for row to be deleted after insert fail)? Also is there a better way to achieve my goal here?

I suggest editing your question such that the table definition matches the sample data.

@TimBiegeleisen I did mention foo and bar are numeric values. And id is an auto increment column.

I don't think you can do this with a CHECK constraint, since it can't do queries. You could do it with BEFORE UPDATE and BEFORE INSERT triggers.

This feels like a normalization problem. You should have another table where key is a primary key, so it can't have both foo: bar and foo: bar2 rows. Then this table can contain foreign keys to that table.

Are there other columns in the table?  If not, what is the advantage in having two identical (except for id) rows?

@RickJames it's purely for constraint checking, not for storing data per se. There are other tables that contain more data for the key.

So, two identical (except for id) with ["foo", "bar"] is OK?

It's ok, but maybe not ideal. All that matters is trying to insert both succeeds.
